# User's phone number is not updated by a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I don't think this is Firebase specific. It may have more to do with await/promises, but I can NOT figure this out.

Writing a Firebase function to allow an authorized user to update another user account. Seems simple. Please note the comments. Notice that 1) the old phone number is undefined (as expected), 2) the new/passed-in phone number is legit, 3) after the assignment, the "new" password is STILL undefined. WHY?!?!?

What am I missing??? (Sorry I cannot make this question more succinct!)

```
module.exports = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  var targetUser = await admin.auth().getUser(data.targetUser.uid)
  // Following rule might not make sense! But it works. We know cuz the following later logs output correctly!
  if (
    Boolean(targetUser) && Boolean(context.auth) &&
    Boolean(context.auth.token.companyToken) &&
    (Boolean(context.auth.token.isAdmin) || context.auth.email === targetUser.email)
  ) {
    // Log output appears from the following!
    console.log(`Phone was ${targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone was undefined" - expected!
    console.log(`Passed-in Phone is ${data.targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone is (402)555-1212" - Yep!
    // Again, ignore the logic here. It's working! I get the embedded log output
    if (context.auth.email === targetUser.email || context.auth.token.companyToken === targetUser.customClaims.companyToken) {
      // the following appears to not execute! I expect targetUser.phoneNumber to be updated!
      // ... it SHOULD become data.targetUser.phoneNumber (i.e. "(402)555-1212")
      targetUser.phoneNumber = (data.targetUser.phoneNumber ? data.targetUser.phoneNumber : targetUser.phoneNumber)
      console.log(`Phone NOW ${targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone is NOW undefined"
      // WTF?!?!? It's still undefined?!?!?
      // THIS IS MY PROBLEM RIGHT HERE! WHY IS phoneNumber STILL UNDEFINED?!?!?!
      // You can ignore the rest...
      return updateUser(targetUser).then(() => {
        return {
          success: true
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return {
        // yadda yadda
        }
      })
    }
  }
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    "not-authorized",
    "Requestor is not authorized to perform this operation on the target user."
  )
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `targetUser` is a [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord) (the Promise returned by the [`getUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuser) method resolves with a `UserRecord`) and you cannot update a `UserRecord` like a simple JavaScript Object.

You need to call the [`updateUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#updateuser) method as follows:

```
const newPhoneNumber = '.....';
const newUserRecord = await admin.auth().updateUser(data.targetUser.uid, {phoneNumber: newPhoneNumber})
console.log(newUserRecord.phoneNumber);
```

---

In addition, note that you are mixing the use of [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method, which is not recommended.

Comment: Yes! That did it! I'm not sure why UserRecord is protected like that - and I must've just missed something in the docs, but I would've NEVER found that. Thank you! And regarding the async/then mixing...I hear you. I'd gone through so many iterations - thinking my issue was delayed updates or some such nonsense - that I was beginning to doubt everything. You're the hero today!

Comment: Glad I could help you Cliff :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with not your code. The problem with the variable declaration, please use the let instead of var, and you are on your way.

```
module.exports = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  //var targetUser = await admin.auth().getUser(data.targetUser.uid);
  // declare the targetUser with let instead of var.
  let targetUser = await admin.auth().getUser(data.targetUser.uid);
  //following later logs output correctly!
  if (
    Boolean(targetUser) && Boolean(context.auth) &&
    Boolean(context.auth.token.companyToken) &&
    (Boolean(context.auth.token.isAdmin) || context.auth.email === targetUser.email)
  ) {
    // Log output appears from the following!
    console.log(`Phone was ${targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone was undefined" - expected!
    console.log(`Passed-in Phone is ${data.targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone is (402)555-1212" - Yep!
    // Again, ignore the logic here. It's working! I get the embedded log output
    if (context.auth.email === targetUser.email || context.auth.token.companyToken === targetUser.customClaims.companyToken) {
      // the following appears to not execute! I expect targetUser.phoneNumber to be updated!
      // ... it SHOULD become data.targetUser.phoneNumber (i.e. "(402)555-1212")
      targetUser.phoneNumber = (data.targetUser.phoneNumber ? data.targetUser.phoneNumber : targetUser.phoneNumber)
      console.log(`Phone NOW ${targetUser.phoneNumber}`) // "Phone is NOW undefined"
      // WTF?!?!? It's still undefined?!?!?
      // THIS IS MY PROBLEM RIGHT HERE! WHY IS phoneNumber STILL UNDEFINED?!?!?!
      // You can ignore the rest...
      return updateUser(targetUser).then(() => {
        return {
          success: true
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return {
        // yadda yadda
        }
      })
    }
  }
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    "not-authorized",
    "Requestor is not authorized to perform this operation on the target user."
  )
})
```

If you still face any issue, then let me know we will find another way.

Comment: Actually this does not make any difference in terms of variable reassigning. See https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Comment: If you read the article carefully you can notice, the let variables have a scope but var does not have any scope it declares variable globally that's why some times var make a mess in code, hence prefer the let for declaration of a variable rather than the var.

Comment: "I prefer the let for declaration of a variable rather than the var" -> I fully agree with that! My point was that the use of `var` is not the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: Changing to "let" did not make any difference. But thank you for offering help!